# Prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n=\infty$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $\{a_n\}$ be an unbounded sequence, $a_n>0$. Let us define: $b_n=\sqrt[n]{a_1^n+a_2^n+...+a_n^n}$. Prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n=\infty$. I tried showing by induction is is non-decreasing but I didn't succeed to do so. I could really use some help.

Comment: The sequence is not likely to be non-decreasing. Imagine a humongous $a_n$ followed by a bunch of tiny terms …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$b_n>\sqrt[n]{M^n}=M>0$$
where $M=\max \{a_1,a_2,\cdots a_n\}$.
Since $a_n$ is unbounded, then $\forall G>0$, however big $G$ is, we can always find a $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\forall n>N$, $M>G$, which yields $b_n>M>G$. Therefore $b_n$ "converges at infinity".

Comment: Then $b_n$ is unbounded but I doesn't derive convergence in the wide sense, or does it? 
Maybe just divergence. It would have been much easier if divergence were convergence in the wide sense.

Comment: What do you mean by  "convergence in the wide sense" ? If you mean "convergence at infinity", then maybe I need to modify my proof a little

Comment: @Meitar I've finished. Now it rigorously shows $b_n \to \infty$.

Comment: Excuse me for bothering you with this. I have not yet fully understood. How can you tell that $\forall G>0$, from some point, the **all** the elements of the tail are bigger then $G$? I thought that the definition of unboundness is the there always exist at least one element bigger then $G$ for every given $G$. I never encountered a claim saying that from some point all the elements are bigger. Can you make yourself more clear? 
By the way, you are really helpful so far. Thank you for replying.

Comment: Oh I'm wrong, it should be $\max {a_i}$, sorry.

Comment: I've made another edit fixing this problem, thanks for pointing out @Meitar

Comment: Great solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try comparing $b_n$ with the result of keeping just one term inside the root.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $$b_{n}^{n}-a_n^n=\sum_{i=2}^n a_{i}^n>0$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n\not=\infty.$
Then there exist a positive real constant $M$ such that $|b_n|\le M$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}.$
Hence $$a_n^n\lt b^n=a_1^n+a_2^n+...+a_n^n\le M^n$$ $$a_n\lt M,\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$